# Launching Surface Duo Emulator Shows "ACPI" error and emulator does not start

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation, surface-duo

When launching the beta Surface Duo emulator, the emulator appears as a blank screen and scrolls an error about ACPI in the status window.

I have already followed the Xamarin instructions for getting the emulator launching:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dual-screen/android/use-emulator?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the wrong version of the Android Emulator being installed. To fix the issue and get the emulator to run:

In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager.

In Android SDK Manager, go to Tools > Android Emulator.

Make sure 29.x is selected, NOT 28.x.

[image: Android SDK Tools screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to mark it as answer after three days. it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Note that since October 2020 the emulator requires version 30 or newer. There's more information on using and troubleshooting at https://learn.microsoft.com/dual-screen/android/emulator/